# prove semiball open at origin implies open everywhere in TVS

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological vector space,given any seminorm $p$.the semiball is defined as $U_p = \{x\mid p(x)<1\}$.

> Prove if it's open at origin(that is exist a neiborbood of origin
> $B_0\subset U_p$ ) , then in fact the semiball is open everywhere.

My attempt:

Our goal is to show any $y\ne 0$ there exist neiborhood around it contains in $U_p$

since for topological vector space,any $\epsilon B_0$ is also basis at origin for $\epsilon>0$.Moreover if $\epsilon\le1$ we further has $\epsilon B\subset B$,due to the neiborhood can be choosen to be balanced.

Now given any point $y\ne 0$ with $p(y)<1$,we have $0<1-p(y)\le 1$ hence $(1-p(y))B_0\subset B_0\subset U_p$ any it's open by homeomorphism of the non zero scalar

Hence we can find neiborhood at $y$ as $y+(1-p(y))B_0 \subset U_p$

To show to last inclusion note that any point in the neiborhood of $y$ has the form $y+(1-p(y))z$ with $z\in B_0\subset U_p$(hence $p(z)<1$) hence $p(y+(1-p(y))z))\le p(y)+ (1-p(y))p(z)< p(y) + (1-p(y))\le1$ hence complete the proof.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Too complicated.  Show for open U, v + U is open.  In fact for any subset A and vector v, A and v + A are homeomorphic.

Comment: @William Elliot I know the fact you claim,but how to prove the semiball is open then based on your fact?And I have used the fact to show it's a n.b at point $y$

Comment: You assumed it was open.  @yi_li

Comment: @William Elliot ,can you make it clear,I don't know what you mean "it" open?Please write formal statement if you have better proof ,you can make it a answer below if you want.

Comment: The problem begins "Prove  if it's open at origin".